# ASP.Net Core: Unobtrusive validation not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

The client side validation in ASP.Net Core (Unlike ASP.Net MVC 5) is not working. I have the following code:

```
public class CountryModel{
    [Required]
    public String Title {get; set;}
}
```

and in my view page

```
using(Html.BeginForm()){
   @Html.LabelFor(x=> x.Title)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=> x.Title)
   @Html.EditorFor(x=> x.Title)
   <Button>Add</Button>
}
```

with the following scripts added to the end of the page:

```
...
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>  
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

But it fails. I have check the script through viewing the source in my browser and the scripts have been loaded properly. I have pointed a break point to my Action API to double check, and any time the add button is pressed I reach the break point meaning the client side validation fails.

Is there any additional configuration in ASP.Net Core?? Because this approach works just fine in MVC 5.

Answer (score 16):

Please make sure your validation-related scripts are placed under the environment which you are using. Development Or Production.

[image]

I was struggling for some time and when I checked my script it was placed in the development section and my app was running using the production environment.

Once I placed the scripts under production it started working !

Answer (score 7):

In my case the problem was quite different.

The validation scripts references were located in the **default/built in `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml`** that I was just adding to my page by adding

```
@section Scripts 
{
     <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial"/>    
}
```

at the end of my View cshtml.

I could see that **it was referenced properly** in Developer Tools, so I thought it's all fine:

[image]

However, it turned out that **the paths in `_ValidationScriptsPartial` were not correct**!
As you can see, there is only minified version available... and in the case of the second one, a `dist` subfolder is missing.

[image]

It was quite surprising, giving this was a boilerplate code that I did not touch.

Answer (score 1):

In My case I forgot to download Jquery, please note to let the jquery validation work, make sure you have all below scripts installed in wwwroot folder in the same order..

**wwwroot folder**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiUoK.png]

**Ordering of scripts in _Layout file**

[image]